# API call in a react JS fiddle

Tags: api, reactjs, jsfiddle

I am hoping for some direction on this issue. I have a project which must be done in a js fiddle. I am trying to make an API call and I want to use superagent(http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) to make the get request, but I can't figure out how to get it to work in the fiddle. Does anyone have any suggestions for this issues, or perhaps a better way to approach the problem? I am new to react so any guidance would be appreciated. Here is a link to the fiddle `enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/Sleahy115/69r7amhs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the superagent lib from cdnjs

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/0.15.7/superagent.min.js"></script>
```

then initialize component's state

```
getInitialState () {
  return {
    repos: []
  };
},
```

and make the query on `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var component = this;
  var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/coma/repos';
  var end = function (error, response) {
    component.setState({repos:response.body})
  };
  var req = superagent.get(url).end(end);
},
```

end result: https://jsfiddle.net/jperelli/p4svwhxp/3/

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. This was a huge help!